# Always have full height columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a html/Angular app.
I am using Twitter bootstrap 4 for layout.
I got three columns 1-2-9 and I need them all to be 1) Same height 2) Always full height of the window.

This I solve with 100vh and it looks good BUT the problem is that since my app can add dynamic content in a long list the columns "stop" being the full height of the screen (since 100vh calculates height when first loading the page).

How can I make sure my columns always adjusts automatically to the full height of the window/browser no matter how much dynamic content I add to it?

Comment: Have you tried using min-height instead of height?

Comment: BS4 has this natively built in. That being said, if you only need 3 columns, it may be a little hacky but take a look at the following; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-groups It might help.

Comment: `since 100vh calculates height when first loading the page` it shouldn't work that way, 100vh is 100vh always even when you add content or resize

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to scroll the dynamic content within the fixed `100vh` columns. If so, you can wrap the inner dynamic content within a `div` and use `overflow` properties for larger data.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 column column-first">
    <div class="scrollable-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>End</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 column column-second">
    <div class="scrollable-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>End</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 column column-third">
    <div class="scrollable-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet viverra neque. Mauris molestie eu tortor a faucibus. Pellentesque porttitor at ex vel condimentum. Mauris ac tortor interdum, mollis felis ac, efficitur neque. Donec volutpat sem vel mauris egestas porta. Phasellus neque justo, accumsan eu lacus ac, ultricies ultrices odio. Vestibulum nibh leo, aliquam ut hendrerit eu, pretium eget magna. Nam fringilla nulla mauris, sit amet scelerisque mauris imperdiet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at eleifend lectus, vitae tincidunt leo. Nullam lacinia hendrerit lacus eu bibendum.</p>
    <p>End</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.scrollable-text{
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
.column-first{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #02547D;
}
.column-second{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0285A8;
}
.column-third{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #02BEC4;
}
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/debrajr/pen/gqZbpx